# The LED on the touchpad on my HP Pavaillion dv6-6080 doesn't work

Tags: touchpad, hp-pavilion, peripherals

I have a HP pavillion dv6-6080 . My touchpad work fine but the led light doesn't work . when I turn it off the red light work prefect but when turn it on nothing happen and the white light doesn't appear. please tell me how I can turn it back?

Answer (score 6):

The way I do it is press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>. It just turns off the light, but not the touchpad. Hope this helps.